# Ubuntu 19.10 Update deleted the whole MySQL and the records

Tags: server, system-installation, apache2, mysql, sql

I have a serious problem with my Ubuntu Server, I updated today from 19.09 to 19.10 but during the install procedure, the system kept throwing messages that MySQL failed to update and the server want to change the mysql.conf file i chosen not to replace that file and after that when i tried to log in to phpmyadmin it said: No such file or directory (On the login screen after typed password and username). It has a lot of data a lot of sensitive data. I need help because on Monday everybody in the office will use it.

```
      Fixing mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 via remove of mysql-client-core-5.7:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 < none -> 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 @un uN Ib >
Broken mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 Ütközik on mysql-server-5.7:amd64 < 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.19.04.2 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering mysql-server-5.7:amd64 -4 as a solution to mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 0
  Added mysql-server-5.7:amd64 to the remove list
Broken mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 Ütközik on mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 < 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.19.04.2 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 -2 as a solution to mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 0
  Added mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 to the remove list
Broken mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 Ütközik on virtual-mysql-server-core:amd64 < none @un H >
  Considering mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 -2 as a solution to mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 0
  Added mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 1:10.3.22-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for mariadb-server-core-10.3 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.7.20-29.24-0ubuntu3 for percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 1:10.3.17-1 for mariadb-server-core-10.3 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
```

Here's some of the error log

Comment: no i managed that database the whole time for 1 month now. but i not created a backup